# vb.net Line numbering in multi line Rich Text Box if line starts with specific condition

Tags: vb.net

Let me start by saying that I'm new to any language of coding besides G-code, and I've researched this until my fingers hurt.  I've actually been working on this project for a little over a year now on my own, and this is the first hurdle I haven't been able to find my way around.

I'm creating an editor for cnc G-code, and i'm trying to add a Re-number function to it.  I'm using a multi line richtextbox to display the the G-code to the user.  I'm trying to edit each line of code that starts with the character "N", and if a line doesn't start with that character then it's left alone.

I figured the best way to do this would be to loop thru the RTB and pass each line into an array.  Then I could use an If statement to see if a cell in the array started with the char "N" or in my case "blockLetter".  Then use the replace function to correct the line Number.

This is what I have so far.

```
Dim increment As Integer = txtLNIncrement.Text
Dim blockLetter As String = txtLNStartTxt.Text
Dim count As Integer = 0
Dim block As Integer = count + increment 

For Each cell As String In frmNC.NcTextBox.Lines
  If cell.StartsWith(blockLetter) Then
    Dim newCell As String = cell.Replace(blockLetter, block)
    block = block + increment
    MessageBox.Show(newCell)
  End If
Next
```

Example of G-code that needs to be renumbered:
`N50 M01
N60 T0101 (TOOL NAME)
N70 M41
N80 G96 S350
N90 M03
N100 M08`

This is what I want:
`N10 M01
N20 T0101 (TOOL NAME)
N30 M41
N40 G96 S350
N50 M03
N60 M08`

This is what I'm getting when I run the code above:
`1050 M01
2060 T0101 (TOOL NAME)
3070 M41
4080 G96 S350
5090 M03
60100 M08`

I believe my issue is that the cell.replace is splitting each cell at the "N" character, and dropping it all together.  Thus adding what I want to see in front of the existing numbers, minus the "N" character.  How can I overwrite the existing block number to the correct ascending block number, and retain the "N" character?  Am I going about this in the correct way, or is there a better way?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace) is not exactly what you need: it replaces **all occurrences** of the pattern.  You'ld change something you don't want to. You could `IndexOf()` on the first space (or `Split()`), then `SubString()` (take the first char), renumber, recombine and save the `Lines` in an array. Then, assign the array to the `Lines` Property (you cannot set a single line value).

Comment: I think I understand what your saying.  Let me give that a try.

Comment: Try splitting each line into words and store in an array, take the first word from the array and replace it with the new value, then set the Richtextbox lines property to that array.

Comment: Are there actually four spaces before the "N"?

Comment: no that was my mistake when I posted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this out:

```
Private increment As Integer = 10
Private blockLetter As String = "N"

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim newLine As String
    Dim values() As String
    Dim lineNumber As Integer = 0
    Dim lines As New List(Of String)(NcTextBox.Lines)
    For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Count - 1
        If lines(i).TrimStart().StartsWith(blockLetter) Then
            values = lines(i).TrimStart(" " & blockLetter.ToCharArray).Split(" ")
            lineNumber = lineNumber + increment
            values(0) = lineNumber
            newLine = blockLetter & String.Join(" ", values)
            lines(i) = newLine
        End If
    Next
    NcTextBox.Lines = lines.ToArray
End Sub
```

Comment: Resolved.  That is amazing.  I have a question about it if you don't mind.  I understand how it works, except for the " " at the begging and ending of the .split.  I get the last one is splitting the string at the first blank space, but what is the first " " for?

Comment: The one at the beginning, which is actually part of the Trim() call, gets rid of **leading** spaces and the "N".  The one at the end says to split the string on spaces.

Comment: @Cpt0bv10usly Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. This aids subsequent viewers to quickly get to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     Dim blockLetter As String = "N"
    Dim increment As Integer = 1
    For i As Integer = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1 Step 1
        Dim fullLine As String = RichTextBox1.Lines(i)

        If fullLine.StartsWith(blockLetter) Then
            Dim numbering As String = fullLine.Remove(RichTextBox1.Lines(i).IndexOf(" "))
            Dim block As Integer = numbering.Substring(1)
            Dim newCell As String = blockLetter & block + increment
            MessageBox.Show(newCell)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Result:

> The Label1.Text will increase with button click.

It's all about Substring() starting from index 1 after 'N', so you will get the number.

Good luck with your coding!

Comment: `cell.Substring(1)` is a string, you cannot assign it to an Integer variable: if the line is `N60 T0101 (TOOL NAME)`, then SubString(1) will be `60 T0101 (TOOL NAME)`. Also, you cannot sum an Integer and a String.

Comment: Thanks Jimi for your point, I edited my answer. Also, I didn't sum String and Integer, because `block` will definitely return a number even if it comes from `Substring()`. You can try it :)

Comment: @kh3e Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.